# Нужно посчитать количество подотрезков массива, у которых количество различных чисел не больше K

Tags: python, алгоритм

Нужно посчитать количество подотрезков массива, у которых количество различных чисел не больше K. У меня есть две функции, первая - возвращает лист всех возможный подотрезков из данного массива, вторая - считает количество различных чисел в подотрезке. Я принимаю на вход N, K, массив N чисел и "склеиваю" все числа массива в одну строку и от нее получаю все сабстринги. А после, считаю такие сабстринги, различность чисел которая не превышает K.

Здесь есть ошибка, но я долблюсь в глаза. Есть ли способ получше решить эту задачу? Спасибо!

```
def get_all_substrings(input_string):
    length = len(input_string)
    return [input_string[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i, length)]


def count_unique(substring):
    return len(set(substring))


my_input = input().split()
n = my_input()[0]
k = int(my_input[1])
l = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
s = ''
cnt = 0

for el in l:
    s += str(el)

subs = get_all_substrings(s)
for ss in subs:
    c = count_unique(ss)
    if c <= k:
        cnt += 1

print(cnt)
```

Comment: Из контекста неясно, что означает фраза "я долблюсь в глаза"

Comment: проверяющая система на олимпиаде не засчитала задачу. не могла понять ошибку долгое время. :) спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используем метод окна с двумя индексами. Создадим структуру для хранения словаря со счётчиками элементов - в Python есть `collections.Counter`.

Установим оба индекса в ноль. Двигаем правый индекс, для каждого нового элемента, входящего в окно, обновляем его счётчик в `Counter`, проверяем размер `Counter` (количество разных элементов с ненулевым счётчиком, назовём его `Distinct`). На каждом шаге этого этапа существует `WinLen = right-left+1` хороших подмассивов, заканчивающихся в `right`, добавляем `WinLen` к результату. Как только `Distinct` превысил `K` - стоп.

Двигаем левый индекс. Для каждого элемента, уходящего из окна, уменьшаем счётчик. Как только `Distinct` (за счёт удаления элементов с нулевым счётчиком) стал меньше `K` - стоп.

Повторяем (чередуем) два предыдущих этапа до конца списка/массива.

Алгоритм линейный, т.к. оба индекса движутся только вперёд (+ затраты на Counter)

Comment: А почему асимптотика линейная? Тут же максимальная сложность явно O(N^2)

Comment: @witaway Каждый элемент один раз входит в окно и один раз выходит, т.е. количество операций порядка 2N.  Если словарь даёт в среднем O(1) на добавление элемента, то получается линейная сложность